# Lifting (a generically 1-1) map to resolutions

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $S_{1},S_{2}$ be quasi-projective varieties over $\mathbb{C}$ of dimension $2$ with only isolated, quotient singularities. Suppose $\phi : S_{1} \rightarrow S_{2}$ is a morphism that is generically 1-1.

Let $\tilde{S_{i}}$ denote minimal (i.e. exceptional divisors contain no $-1$ curves) resolutions of the $S_{i}$, can we lift $\phi$ uniquely to a morphism $\tilde{\phi} : \tilde{S_{1}} \rightarrow \tilde{S_{2}}$?

Comment: Not in general. Consider the map induced by $\mathbb{C}[x^2,xy,y^2]\subset\mathbb{C}[x,y]$. Then $S_1$ is smooth, but $S_2$ has an $A_1$ singularity. It is easy to check that the morphism does not lift from $S_1$ to $\widetilde{S}_2$.

Comment: Thanks for the counter-example! It turns out that in the case I am interested the map is generically 1-1 (apologies for not including this in the question), is this likely to help?